# how to select option based on value

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js

I have stuck in following issue

I have a select drop down which is getting populated by AJAX call my requirement is to select option by default ,I know how to do JQUERY

In short Please let me know whats the equivalent of $(#id).val() in angular
Following is snippet

```
 <select  id="eventypeee" ng-change="appendselected()"
  ng-model="eventtypelistforcity.selected" 
  ng-options="option.eventId as option.eventAliasName for option in eventtypelistforcity | orderBy:'eventAliasName'">
  <!-- test -->
</select>
```

i want selected eventid =11 is selected to

Comment: `ng-model` is two way bind, so if you want default selected value then assign that value to `ng-model`. i.e `$scope.eventtypelistforcity.selected`

Comment: if eventtypelistforcity.selected=11, then that event will be selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you create a separate model for your selected option rather than pointing it to the same object you use to create the options. Try this:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gqIY7qeNjHpzbQecBLVg)

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select  
      id="eventypeee" 
      ng-change="appendselected()"
      ng-model="selectedOption" 
      ng-options="option.eventId as option.eventAliasName for option in eventtypelistforcity | orderBy:'eventAliasName'"
    ></select> 

    <pre>{{selectedOption}}</pre>
  </body>
```

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.eventtypelistforcity = [ 

    {
      eventId: 1,
      eventAliasName: 'foo'
    },

    {
      eventId: 2,
      eventAliasName: 'bar'
    },

    {
      eventId: 3,
      eventAliasName: 'baz'
    } 

  ];

  // defined a model for your selected option 
  // you access the selected option through this..
  $scope.selectedOption = $scope.eventtypelistforcity[0].eventId;


  $scope.appendSelected = function(){

  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive like this :

```
<select id="eventypeee" ng-change="appendselected()" ng-model="eventtypelistforcity.selected">
    <option ng-selected="option.eventId==11" data-ng-repeat="option in eventtypelistforcity" value="{{ option.eventId }}">{{ option.eventAliasName }}</option>
</select>
```

JS :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.eventtypelistforcity = [ 
        {
           eventId: 11,
           eventAliasName: 'Event11'
        } ,
        {
           eventId: 1,
           eventAliasName: 'foo'
        },
        {
           eventId: 2,
           eventAliasName: 'bar'
        }

    ];

    //Define your model corresponding to your select value
    $scope.eventtypelistforcity.selected $scope.eventtypelistforcity[0].eventId;

});
```

DEMO: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFrDJjOJEl3n9anjnzLp?p=preview)